# Create a Migration Final save button is disabled

Tags: azure, ms-access, migrate

I resolved my issue on my own.  After doing this I reread the question and with the knowledge I now have I as a different user I would have known exactly what I needed and would have answered that user with about 3 sentences

1. Reboot your PC after setting up the Azure database
2. Review the table schema of your access database and make any name changes that might be a conflict with sql server
3. Get SSMA which is the migration tool for Access -  Must have
   4 - follow the instructions - so easy

I stand by the question.  Sometimes we tend to either over engineer a question or answer when the most obvious is the simplest
Problem - set up db on azure now I can't figure out how to migrate an access db because that is not an option like other db's in the list.

Answer - Oh I had the problem when I first signed up with Azure - you need to do the following

(See above)

First of all I am not stupid by any means and have been developing software since 1992, but the interface for this whole Azure thing is just horrible and the overhead to do anything is so extreme.  With that said I created and azure database service using my company ID  Created the server and database  Went to the migration services.  I am migrating a mission critical access accdb backend to this azure site to see how it performs  At first I thought I could use SSMS locally to see the database but I could not.  So, knowing that there is no more "upsizing" I figured the site would walk me through.  I answered the questions ( none about the source) but when I try to save or continue the buttons are disabled  I did install the hybrid worker as instructed as well  I do not understand where why there cant just be an option that says upload an acees database and it go from there.  lol  or why I can't see it from SSMS on my machine

Comment: Maybe try to write this question in a bit cleaner way and then copy the answer from your question as an actual answer. Might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tool for the job: [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 8.12 for Access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255).